# Tomcat 9 : 404 error

Tags: spring, tomcat, model-view-controller, intellij-idea

Can any one help me with this error? I am using Tomcat 9.0.0.M20 as the server in my Spring project.

> HTTP Status [404] – [Not Found]
>   Type Status Report
>   Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the Target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
>   Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M20

Here is my code:

home.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>maventest2</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>MavenTest2 Spring demo</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Here is the Dispatcher servlet (dispatcher-servlet.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springhello"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Here is the Spring controller (HelloController.java):

```
package com.springhello.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home(){
        return "home";
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the URL you are using to access the spring project.

Comment: Hi Rajith, 

 http://localhost:8081/co.spring/ 
Thank you: